# Dealing with Sharepoint locked Site Collections

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, spsite

I am playing with an application that can crawl the contents of sharepoint server. But I got a problem while working with Locked Site collections.

There are some methods that cannot be used with locked site collections. It throws an exception telling me the contents are blocked.

So I want to handle this more gracefully by checking whether a collection is locked. How can I do this?

Update : One more addition. The site collection has been locked using stsadm NOT programatically. So the [SPSite.ReadLocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.readlocked.aspx) property has no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the source code of the setsitelock command; typing

stsadm -o setsitelock -lock readonly

results in (pseudo-code):

```
    SPSite.ReadLocked = false;
    SPSite.WriteLocked = false;
    SPSite.ReadOnly = true;
```

The ReadOnly property is interesting, because it is only true when the lock is of type 'readonly'.